# mosek parameter settings in cvxpy

Tags: cvxpy, cvx

I am trying to set "mosek_param" settings, but, am getting errors. For instance, for the following case

```
MSK_IPAR_INTPNT_SOLVE_FORM

Controls whether the primal or the dual problem is solved.
Default:
  "FREE"
Accepted:
  "FREE", "PRIMAL", "DUAL"
Example:
  param.MSK_IPAR_INTPNT_SOLVE_FORM = 'MSK_SOLVE_FREE'
Groups:
  Interior-point method
```

from https://docs.mosek.com/9.0/toolbox/parameters.html --> I tried

```
prob.solve(solver=MOSEK,
mosek_params={mosek.iparam.intpnt_solve_form: mosek.solve.primal},     # mosek.iparam.presolve_use:mosek.presolvemode.off
verbose=True)
```

but, run into errors .... the commented part works.

When I was working in Matlab --> using

```
cvx_solver_settings('MSK_IPAR_INTPNT_SOLVE_FORM','MSK_SOLVE_PRIMAL')
```

worked well for me. But, doesn't work in the present case. Also, I was able to set precision as follows

```
cvx_precision low
```

but, cannot do so now. Is there another way to do both of these in cvxpy? thank you.

PS: this question has also been posted in the CVXPY forum --> https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cvxpy/MEAewGMlqjI

---

Below is an example

```
# Solves a bounded least-squares problem.

import mosek
from cvxpy import *
import numpy

# Problem data.
m = 10
n = 5
numpy.random.seed(1)
A = numpy.random.randn(m, n)
b = numpy.random.randn(m)

# Construct the problem
x = Variable(n)
objective = Minimize(sum_squares(A*x - b))
constraints = [0 <= x, x <= 1]
prob = Problem(objective, constraints)

prob.solve(solver=MOSEK,
mosek_params={mosek.iparam.intpnt_solve_form: mosek.solve.primal},     # mosek.iparam.presolve_use:mosek.presolvemode.off
verbose=True)
```

which gives me the [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOMrz.png). I also tried using 'MSK_IPAR_INTPNT_SOLVE_FORM'   = 'MSK_SOLVE_PRIMAL' but to no avail.

Comment: What exactly errors did you run into when you tried it in cvxpy? Please post the whole error message. How can anyone help without knowing what the error was?

Comment: Regarding precision, you would have to set the parameters mentioned here https://docs.mosek.com/9.1/pythonapi/solving-conic.html#adjusting-optimality-criteria

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek I just added an example along with the error message I get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at

https://docs.mosek.com/9.1/pythonapi/parameters.html#mosek.iparam.intpnt_solve_form

The correct form is

`mosek.solveform.primal`

Comment: Thank you for your help! can you pls tell me how the tolerance precision in https://docs.mosek.com/9.1/pythonapi/solving-conic.html#adjusting-optimality-criteria relates to various `cvx precision` tolerances in http://cvxr.com/cvx/doc/solver.html#interpreting? In particular, I would like to know which params I could set to achieve the scenario of `cvx_precision low`

Comment: @user11726509 In most cases you have to relax all parameters mentioned in the table simultaneously. The question is why you would want to do it?

Comment: i would like to avoid tuning each of those (4) tolerances: ε_p, ε_d, ε_g, ε_i
thus, I was looking for an equivalent of cvx_precision low that adjusts the (3) tolerances--ϵ_solver,ϵ_standard,ϵ_reduced--each of which are defined in terms of Matlab's machine precision: ϵ. However, I am not sure how these (3) tolerances translate in terms of mosek's (4) tolerances:? Thus, I was looking at the documentation of cvx_precision here: https://github.com/cvxr/CVX/blob/master/commands/cvx_precision.m
but, didn't really see the connection. Any assistance towards this would be much appreciated.

Comment: using `cvx_precision low` worked well for me when i was working on the Matlab end.

Comment: @user11726509 You would have to look into cvx code and see exactly what it does when precision is set to low. Surely it can be reverse engineered to see what parameters are set.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek Hi, it's me again :) When setting `prob.solve(solver=cp.MOSEK, mosek_params={'MSK_DPAR_INTPNT_CO_TOL_REL_GAP': 1e-4}, verbose=True)`, it just igonres that parameter. Same thing happens with Gurobi and ECOS. Why doesn't cvxpy take these arguments correclty?